# Background task after logging out

Tags: bash, sleep, sudo

I am trying to make a surveillance camera turn on after a specified amount of time after I leave.

I imagined it to be something like this:

```
sleep 60 && sudo service motion start &> /dev/null &
```

but the background task seems to get deleted when I log out. Is there a way to make it stick around even after I leave? AND also to have the root permissions?

EDIT:
Okay I ended up making a script that does it instead of using a single command, it looks about like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if (( $UID > 0 )); then
        echo "Only root can run this script"
        exit 1
fi

if [ -z $1 ]; then
    TIMEOUT=30
else
    TIMEOUT=$1
fi


sleep $TIMEOUT && service motion start &>/dev/null &

exit 0
```

Answer (score 1):

use nohup:

```
sudo nohup service motion start &
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it asks for the password in the background. Otherwise I'd think it'd be a good idea as it seems to launch as root and stay there even after I log out. So if only I can make it ask for a password first.

Comment: I like anishsane's idea to run a "minimal sudo" beforehand. Try `sudo echo "going to start service motion now";sudo nohup service motion start &`. (There are other possibilities: allow your account to use "service" via /etc/sudoers or make your camera accessible to your account so there is no need to run service as root.)

Comment: I would like to keep the service command and camera protected from other users than root. The problem with this is to wait for an amount of time and then running sudo(authentication might have timed out) and also stay there when logging out. So I made a script that does what I need(see original post).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `nohup`, you can also use `screen`:

```
screen
sudo service motion start
```

Then type `CTRL+a` then `d` to detach the screen.

To reattach, you can simply use:

```
screen -x
```

For more information:

```
man screen
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues here:

1. Executing something after you log out. (I guess you are planning to put it in ~/.bash_logout, which is a good idea)
2. Executing it under `sudo`, which may be difficult.

Below are the common approaches:

1. ```
   nohup sudo ( sleep 60; service motion start ) &
   #Has issues, if sudo authentication is not complete till this point, since background process cannot prompt you for sudo password. Better to call `sudo true` or `sudo echo -n` or similar dumb command, under sudo before calling the actual command.

   #You  may be tempted to call sudo only for service command, instead of entire command.
   However, there is a risk that if sleep interval is long enough, then sudo token may expire.
   ```
2. ```
   echo service motion start | sudo at now+1min
   #The problem with this command is that the granularity is minute level, not seconds level. Otherwise, this looks clean to me.
   ```

Based on your requirement, you can choose either of them, or any other mechanism mentioned in the other answers.